# scroll #mainContainer to element in polymer using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I am using Polymer "core_scaffold" and I want to perform some jQuery function on #mainContainer (Id).
I tried to use the following code

```
$('#mainContainer').on('scroll', function() {
        // custom code 
});
```

could anyone let me know how to get the scroll function on #mainContainer on polymer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no point in using jQuery for this.
Looking at core_scaffold code at https://github.com/Polymer/core-scaffold/blob/master/core-scaffold.html it looks that there is an "scroll" event emitted.

```
scroll: function(e) {
  this.fire('scroll', {target: e.detail.target}, this, false);
}
```

Your ID selector might be off. just try:

```
document.querySelector('[name="core-scaffold"]').addEventListener('scroll', function(event){ console.log(event)}, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in the selector. mainContainer is in the shadowdom of core-scaffold and can not be pierced with regular selectors. but core-scaffold provides a property for getting the scrollable element. i don't know jquery very well so i will use javascript and you can convert.

```
var scroller = document.querySelector('core-scaffold').scroller; 
scroller.onscroll = function (e) {
  // do something while scrolling
};
```